# Calling Function in a Modular Javascript file triggered undefined object error

Tags: javascript, jquery

I recently started with Modular javascript files. But I am facing an issue when trying to call internal functions. My script is like this

```
var myTeamMaster=(function(){
    alert(function1());
    var function1=function()
    {
        alert("function1");
    }
    var function2=function()
    {
        alert("function2");
    };
    return
    {
        function1:function1,
        function2:function2
    }
})();
```

As you can see Im just calling function1() from the alert. Its triggering object expected error. I didnt understand why?

Comment: You do not have a function declaration, so `function1` is not hoisted. You also need to put the `{` for the returned object on the same line as the `return`

Comment: Can you please help me how to declare that.. as an answer

Comment: See the linked canonical